# Recursive method returning empty value

Tags: java, recursion

**Description**

My goal is to store all file paths in a file. To do that I built a recursive method which browse a specific folder. However, the result is still empty ...

**Code**

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    String files = browseFolder("", new File("blablalbla/.../toto"));

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("result/"));
    writer.write(files);
    writer.close();
}

private static String browseFolder(String result, File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            browseFolder(result, fileEntry);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getPath());
            result += fileEntry.getPath() + "\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

All files are displayed in the console thanks to the `sysout`. However, my result file is empty.

Any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: It's considered a bad idea to assign values to a parameter within the method body. For this problem, you should probably read the answers to [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @ernest_k Thank you. Do you think that is the reason why I'm facing this error : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: Nope. I *guess* you could get that error if you called your method with `"/"` (or `"C:\"`) as `folder` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the recursive call to `browseFolder` will not change its parameter, because `String` is immutable. A string variable that is passed to a method will always stay the same after that method returns. This means that as long as the `blablalbla/.../toto` directory is full of subdirectories, your main call to `browseFolder` will return an empty string, because you are not doing anything to `result`.

You *could* append the return value of recursive `browseFolder` calls to `result`, like this:

```
private static String browseFolder(String result, File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            // here:
            result += browseFolder(result, fileEntry);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getPath());
            result += fileEntry.getPath() + "\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, this creates a new string every time you do this, so it is quite wasteful. You can use a `StringBuilder` (which is mutable!) instead.

```
private static StringBuilder browseFolder(StringBuilder result, File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            browseFolder(result, fileEntry);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getPath());
            result.append(fileEntry.getPath()).append("\n");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The caller will have to change too. You can do `.toString` on a `StringBuilder` to convert it to `String`.

```
String files = browseFolder(new StringBuilder(), new File("blablalbla/.../toto")).toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Due to immutability of `String` (variable `result` always references the same string value in memory), you should use concat to save the result, as it actually creates a new reference to a new string value.

```
if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
    result += browseFolder(result, fileEntry);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In

```
browseFolder(result, fileEntry);
```

you are ignoring the `String` returned by the recursive method, which is why you get an empty `String` in the end.

Instead of concatenating `String`s, which results in many `String` instances being created, I suggest you pass a `StringBuilder` to your recursive method.

This way your method can modify the `StringBuilder`, and doesn't have to return a value.

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder files = new StringBuilder();
    browseFolder(files, new File("blablalbla/.../toto"));

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("result/"));
    writer.write(files.toString());
    writer.close();
}

private static void browseFolder(StringBuilder result, File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            browseFolder(result, fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getPath());
            result.append(fileEntry.getPath()).append("\n");
        }
    }
}
```